# How to use Rx Observable with generic EventHandler<T>?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The following code works

```
var mouseTracker = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(form1, "MouseMove");
//for Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

But how to make the Observable.FromEventPattern to take EventHandler <T> ? Something like

```
var mouseTracker = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<StockQuote>>(_board, "QuoteUpdated");
//for board_QuoteUpdated(object sender, StockQuote stockQuote)
```

**Edit**

Answer from Gluck works. I need to change the FromEventPattern to FromEvent.

```
var quoteObserver = Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler<StockQuote>, StockQuote>(
h => (_, sq) => h(sq),
eh => _board.QuoteUpdated += eh,
eh => _board.QuoteUpdated -= eh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a generic type `EventArgs<T>`.

Assuming that what you need is to create an observable for an event which doesn't follow the standard event pattern (in your case it'd mean `StockQuote` type doesn't extend `EventArgs`), then `FromEventPattern` can't be used.

But you can still use `FromEvent`:

```
IObservable<StockQuote> obs = Observable.FromEvent<QuoteUpdatedDelegate, StockQuote>(
    h => (_, sq) => h(sq),
    eh => _board.QuoteUpdated += eh,
    eh => _board.QuoteUpdated -= eh);
```

Comment: You are right. I mean EventHandler<T>, not EventArgs<T>